# Xaramin help, "invalid resource directory name res layout1" error as soon as I make a new layout

Tags: c#, android, resources

I've seen this problem persist around the internet with others, as I have tried to find a solution, for it has hit me too; (The error is pretty vague which doesn't help but here goes) when I create a new Xaramin project and then add a new layout, I get an error "invalid resource directory name res layout1". I've tried renaming the "Resource" folder to "res", I changed the Build action of the files in the folder to 'Android Resource' and 'Android Asset' alternatively, but those attempts didn't solve the issue. Has anyone had this spontaneous problem? I've literally written no code, haha. I've also checked, I'm up to date with Xaramin, stable build. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues a while ago. If you haven't done so already, try cleaning and rebuilding the project. Possibly even restart Xamarin or Visual Studio. That might help sometimes. In the worst case scenario, you might have to create a new project, and copy your existing files into that project.

Comment: Yeah been cleaning and rebuilding quite a few times, but I'll keep tinkering around and scrounging for a solution; just kind of sucks that I have to go through this as I was really excited to try out Xaramin but can't even get started.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue and was unable to resolve it with the previously posted solution. I solved this problem by ensuring that the new layout files I was creating were placed under the "resources\values" directory. I had been mistakenly placing them in the "resources" directory and moving them solved the problem immediately.

Comment: NOTE: using any other directory within "Resources" may cause references to "Resource.Designer.cs" to fail. I tried placing a new layout in the "resources\layout" directory and it caused problems.